# Requestverificationtoken not populating when calling action from cross domain iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, antiforgerytoken

I am calling my mvc post action method from a different website which is cross domain. My action method has ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. The call to the action method fails with 500 error. It throws antiforgery token exception. How can I allow my action method to be executed from this cross domain without removing ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly trying to violate the basic functionality of the Anti-Forgery token.

Why would you want to validate AntiForgery token when you want the post method to be accessed from another domain.

The basic use of this token is to stop malicous posts from other domains.

When the page is first loaded a token is sent from the server to client which is later matched when an post request comes to the server.

Now since you have this in another domain, the token is not there when the post occurs.

Comment: Because I am calling same action method through my web app also.

Comment: Its very simple. If you want the post to be accessible across multiple domains you have to remove the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. This entire concept is based on cookies and it is impossible to share cookies across domains.